# How edit the content of a data extract in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm creating an extract from a table hosted on MS SQL Server in Tableau.

After I create the data extract, is there any way I can enable the end users to edit the data extract content? Something like an interface?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Tableau Data Extract API (and publicly released products) do **not** allow you to modify the contents of an extract.

You **can** append new data rows to an extract, or refresh (i.e. regenerate) an extract.

Think of extracts like datamarts -- read-only snapshots of a portion of some other data store, designed to allow efficient analysis and reporting. They aren't intended to replace databases.

If you want users to make live updates, consider using a database and some sort of tech stack to allow form based updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `web-authoring` in Tableau.

you can publish the extract to server and allow the users to connect to this `data source` for creating their own reports 
using the server version of `Tableau` this can also be referred as `Adhoc Reporting`

[More Info](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/server-desktop-web-edit-differences)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did go through the link you provided, it seems that this is only for the users to play around the report attributes rather than modifying the data source itself.